# Avoid a time-consuming step in a reactive expression in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shiny-reactivity

In my Shiny app, users can upload a file which is stored as a `reactive` dataframe. Inside the reactive expression that is shown below, I call an external time-consuming function (called performDigestion) which requires several seconds to complete.

```
fastafile_data <- reactive(){
    inFile_fastafile <- input$fastaFile
    req(inFile_fastafile)
    ext <- tools::file_ext(inFile_fastafile$datapath)
    validate(need(ext == "fasta", "Please upload a fasta file"))
    dt.seq <- readAAStringSet(inFile_fastafile$datapath)
    tbl <- performDigestion(dt.seq) ##the time-consuming step
    return(tbl)
  }
```

Next, I render a Datatable to present the results of the **fastafile_data** in the UI:

```
output$dt_fastafile <- DT::renderDataTable({
withProgress(message = 'Computation in progress, this step might take a while. Please wait...', {
  incProgress(1/1)
  fastafile_data()
  })
  }, options = list(scrollX = TRUE, dom = 'lfrtip', pageLength = 10, lengthMenu = c(10, 25, 50, 100)), rownames = FALSE)
```

In the UI, I also have two additional components (a `sliderInput` and a `numericInput`) and in the server-side I handle their values through two `observeEvent`s .

What I would like to achieve is to update the **fastafile_data** dataframe every time any of these two additional components is triggered without reading the input$fastaFile again and re-running the time consuming performDigestion() function. I would ideally like to trigger the above reactive process again only when a new file is uploaded by the user.

I think the problem here is in my logic and/or there exists a smarter way to do it in ShinyR that I'm currently missing? Can you please point me to the right direction?

**EDIT:**

When I try to handle the reactive `fastafile_data` through a second reactive `fastafile_data_new` the first `fastafile_data` is re-executed.

```
fastafile_data_new <- reactive({
    dt <- fastafile_data()
    ##### the condition I'd like to apply
    dt$identifiable <- ifelse(dt$length >= min_peptide_length$choice & dt$length <= max_peptide_length$choice & dt$`mass [Da]` < max_peptide_mass$choice, 1, 0)
    return(dt)
  })
```

Comment: You can just define a new reactive that takes `fastafile_data` and the other UI inputs as input and filter it. Then you use this new reactive to render your table

Comment: I updated my code. As suggested, I tried to use a second reactive `fastafile_data_new` which takes as an input the `fastafile_data` but every time a change in the UI is triggered (either from the `sliderInput` or the `numericInput`), then the second reactive expression is re-executed along with the first reactive (with the time-consuming function).

Comment: Can you provide a MRE? In general, the first reactive shouldn't be triggered in this case

Comment: Try `dt <- isolate(fastafile_data())`.  As @starja stated, it is hard to help you without a MRE.